# Why is datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp raising OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, datetime

I 'm trying to convert the Epoch timestamp `1549392388289` (which came from a web API) to a `datetime` object. When I try

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1549392388289)
```

A `OSError` exception is raised

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

But the same Epoch timestamp works just fine using an [online converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

What is causing this exception? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: can you show the error traceback?

Comment: I personally get a ValueError for an out of range year (51068), not an OSError

Comment: Posix timestamps should be in seconds, but it looks like you've got milliseconds.

Answer (score 8):

You have multiplied the timestamp by 1000. This works as expected:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1549392388.289))
```

Comment: Effectively, this match today, a minute ago.

Comment: Ah, the API I'm getting timestamps from changed from seconds to milliseconds. Very annoying.